# Can powershell be used to create local user accounts in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell

I was able to create a local account in a remote machine through powershell terminal using the following code :

```
[ADSI]$server="WinNT://servername"

$HelpDesk=$server.Create("User","HelpDesk")

$HelpDesk.SetPassword("H3lpD3>K")

$HelpDesk.SetInfo()
```

This works fine.

I tried using New-LocalUser from powershell, but getting the following error :
"The term 'New-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

How to use powershell commands for local user account creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "New-LocalUser" cmdlet.  You can do it with code you have, by replacing 'servername' with 'localhost'.

```
[ADSI]$server="WinNT://localhost"

$HelpDesk=$server.Create("User","HelpDesk")

$HelpDesk.SetPassword("H3lpD3>K")

$HelpDesk.SetInfo()
```

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a way to do the same using a single powershell command?

Comment: Yes.  You can turn that into a function.  See get-help about_functions for more information.

Comment: Thanks..1 more question.For Active Directory, there is AD cmdlet to use in powershell. Is there any similar cmdlet for managing local user account?

Comment: No, there are no native cmdlets for that.

Comment: 1 more doubt. Is it possible to create a local user account using remote windows machine using powershell commands?

Comment: Isn't this a cmdlet ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser